# PDF Table object list to csv format in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, pdf, tabula

I am trying to build a panel database by appending tables by rows using same column names for data tables in pp. 149-157 from this pdf file:

https://www.uv.mx/personal/clelanda/files/2013/02/Garber-2000-Famous-first-bubbles.pdf

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
!pip install tabula-py
!pip install pandas 

import pandas as pd
import tabula
from google.colab import files
def getLocalFiles():
   _files = files.upload()
   if len(_files) >0:
      for k,v in _files.items():
        open(k,'wb').write(v)
getLocalFiles()

#directory path
!ls 

#Reading pdf tables

file = "bubbles.pdf"
path = 'bubbles.pdf'
tables = tabula.read_pdf(path, pages = [149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157], columns= (1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
print(tables)

#passing to csv format 
from pandas import DataFrame
df=pd.DataFrame(page_1)
print(df)
df.to_csv('test.csv', index= False)
```

This is the output data:

[image]

In which way could I append all pdf tables?,
thanks in advance

Comment: Not exactly sure on the question, but `pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)` might help.